# Better way to filter a data frame with dplyr using OR?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame in **R** with columns `subject1` and `subject2` (which contain Library of Congress subject headings). I'd like to filter the data frame by testing whether the subjects match an approved list. Say, for example, that I have this data frame.

```
data <- data.frame(
  subject1 = c("History", "Biology", "Physics", "Digital Humanities"),
  subject2 = c("Chemistry", "Religion", "Chemistry", "Religion")
)
```

And suppose this is the list of approved subjects.

```
condition <- c("History", "Religion")
```

What I want to do is filter by either subject1 or subject2:

```
subset <- filter(data, subject1 %in% condition | subject2 %in% condition)
```

That returns items 1, 2, and 4 from the original data frame, as desired.

Is that the best way to filter by multiple fields using *or* rather than *and* logic? It seems like there must be a better, more idiomatic way, but I don't know what it is.

Maybe a more generic way to ask the question is to say, if I combine subject1 and subject2, is there a way of testing if any value in one vector matches any value in another vector. I'd like to write something like:

```
subset <- filter(data, c(subject1, subject2) %in% condition)
```

Comment: Your code (`filter(data, subject1 %in% condition | subject2 %in% condition)`)  works for me

Comment: It works for me too. I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: Thanks for editing the post for clarification.

Comment: Indeed, the `should return` was a bit confusing.

Answer (score 14):

I'm not sure whether this approach is better. At least you don't have to write the column names:

```
library(dplyr)
filter(data, rowSums(sapply(data, "%in%", condition)))
#             subject1  subject2
# 1            History Chemistry
# 2            Biology  Religion
# 3 Digital Humanities  Religion
```

Comment: `Reduce('|', lapply(data, '%in%', condition))` will be much faster