# Filtering/subsetting in R applied to multiple columns

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, subset

```
Index   odx1    odx2    odx3    odx4    odx5
1       123     0       0       0       0
2       0       321     0       0       0
3       0       0       0       123     0
4       0       321     0       0       0
5       0       0       0       0       0
```

I've attached a sample of my dataset above. I would like to filter across multiple columns in R to subset my dataset that contains for example 123 or 321.

What I've attempted so far is to use dplyr -

```
df %>% filter(., odx1==123 | odx2==123 | odx3==123 | odx4==123 | odx5==123 | odx1==321| odx2==321| odx3==321| odx4==321| odx5==321)
```

Although the above would work, is there a cleaner more simplified method of doing this?

My actual dataset contains odx1-odx25 and I have a list of about 15 strings to filter for across about 100K rows.

EDIT:

The actually dataset contains random strings of numbers, but I just used 0 for visibility and simplicity as an example.

```
Index   odx1    odx2    odx3    odx4    odx5
1       123     421     532     414     981
2       243     321     765     132     321
3       144     322     587     123     444
4       655     321     459     091     676
5       456     421     523     431     768
```

Comment: How about `df[rowSums(df == 123 | df == 321) > 0, ]`

Comment: If the data is always in this general format (just want to get rid of observations that consist of all `0`s, then a little faster (in terms of both keystrokes and computational time) solution would be: `df[rowSums(df!=0)!=0,]`

Answer (score 3):

As in my comment:

If the data is always in this general format (just want to get rid of observations that consist of all 0s, then a little faster (in terms of both keystrokes and computational time) solution would be:

```
df[rowSums(df[, -1]!=0)!=0,]
```

Comment: You need to exclude index column, so df[, -1] in the rowSums? Also, if speed is the key, `system.time(df[rowSums(df[, -1]) != 0, ]); 
   user  system elapsed 
  2.744   0.798   3.894 
system.time(df[rowSums(df!=0)!=0,])
   user  system elapsed 
  5.086   1.617   6.939 `

Comment: You're right. In my head Index was the row.names (since sometimes people accidentally include them), and I had dropped it prior to doing the above code. I edited my code as such. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if you need to filter on an explicit set of values (you said you have 15 strings to filter on), you can use this to filter across all columns.

```
library(dplyr)
conditions.to.match <- c(123, 321)
df %>% filter(Reduce('|', lapply(df, '%in%', conditions.to.match)))
```

([Idea from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21637512/2005219))

Answer (score 1):

Base package:

```
df[apply(df, 1, function(x) {any(x == 123 | x == 321)}),]
```

`dplyr` package

```
library(dplyr)
filter(df, rowSums(mutate_each(df, funs(. %in% c(123, 321)))) >= 1L)
```

Output:

```
  Index odx1 odx2 odx3 odx4 odx5
1     1  123    0    0    0    0
2     2    0  321    0    0    0
3     3    0    0    0  123    0
4     4    0  321    0    0    0
```